# Resetting UISearchbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

Is there a possibility to reset a UISearchbar with searchDisplayController programmatically which is active and already contains text?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
       searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
       searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
       [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

This solution is working, but there is still text in the searchBar. If i add those lines of code:

```
searchBar.text = @"";
```

There is always a black transparent view left.

Any solutions?

Comment: try 

     searchBar.text = nil;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here ya go.  This is a delegate method called when the user hits cancel.  If you want to wire it up differently just declare your search bar as an outlet and reference it.  Anyway:

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];   
}
```

Comment: Don't understand how this should work? Please read my updated question.

Comment: I think the best question at this point is to ask exactly what behavior you are looking for?  On my search bars, I rarely use the SB with the SRC.  I just use a SB and take care of how it is presented myself.  If you are looking to "reset it" then the code I provided is all you need.  If you are looking to "get it out of the way" then I use the scrollViewWillBeginDragging delegate method to get the keyboard out of the way and let the user scroll through the results.

Comment: I can send you a complete example of how I do things (for example I almost always use a TableView and not a TableViewController and put the SB in a fixed position above the TV so it is always accessible).  Like I said, knowing exactly what you want this to look like and how you want it to behave would really help us help you better.

Comment: I'm using the SearchDisplayController and i would like to fix the bug in my app so the black transparent view will disappear after didSelectRowAtIndexPath: get called.

Comment: Do you think this is possible or do i have do go without to the SearchDisplayController to control the behavior of the searchBar like described above.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm going to go without the searchDisplayController.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is UISearchDisplayController.active

From the SDK:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isActive) BOOL active
```

If you set this value directly, any change is performed without animation. Use setActive:animated: if a change in state should be animated.

When the user focus in the search field of a managed search bar, the search display controller automatically displays the search interface. You can use this property to force the search interface to appear.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is so old it has dust. Still here we are in swift so

```
<#your UISearchController variable#>.isActive = false
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to retire the firstResponder

Comment: resign first responder will dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder]
```

Comment: This solution keeps the searchBar as it is and hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can also explicitly hide the resultsTableView, if that's what you want:

```
searchDC.searchResultsTableView.hidden=YES;
```

(searchDC is an instance of UISearchDisplayController)

This will help you with hiding the Cancel button and stuff: http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=418

Comment: I would prefer a searchBar which is empty and isn't activated -> no chancelButton